# How to send extra parameter on SelectedIndexChanged?

Tags: asp.net, parameter-passing, selectedindexchanged, extra

Is there any way to send extra parameter to SelectedIndexChanged function?

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList 
                    ID="rblMeetingPlace" 
                    SelectedValue = '<%# Bind("intMtgLoc") %>'
            *OnSelectedIndexChanged = "Validate('txtMeetPlaceOther')"*
                    runat="server" 
                    RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
 >
<asp:ListItem Value="1">Workshop</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2">Service provider agency</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="3">Advocacy organization</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="4">Public Space</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="5">Other (specify): </asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="" Text="" style="display: none" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMeetPlaceOther" Text='<%# Bind("strMtgLocOth") %>' 
runat="server" />
```

I have couple of radiobuttonlist and I want to enable the textboxes when "Other" is selected.
I am thinking of sending the textbox's id to enable it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it this way:

```
<asp:radiobuttonlist id="rbl1" runat="server" 
    RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
    AutopostBack="true"
    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("intMtgLoc") %>' 
    OnselectedIndexChanged="rbl1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Workshop</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Service provider agency</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">Advocacy organization</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4">Public Space</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="5">Other (specify): </asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="" style="display:none" />
        </asp:radiobuttonlist>
<asp:textbox id="txtMeetPlaceOther" text='<%# Bind("strMtgLocOth") %>' runat="server" />
<asp:textbox id="TextBox1" enabled="false" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
<asp:textbox id="TextBox2" enabled="false" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
```

and in code-behind:

```
protected void rbl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        *yourValidatorName*.Validate();
        if (Convert.ToInt32(rbl1.SelectedValue) == 5)
        {
            TextBox1.Enabled = true;
            TextBox2.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            TextBox1.Enabled = false;
            TextBox2.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

reply to comment:
 First of all you should set `OnSelectedIndexChanged` for all `RadioButtonLists` event handlers. Here - `rbl_SelectedIndexChanged`.
Then in code behind:

```
protected void rbl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            TextBox[] textboxes = new TextBox[] { TextBox1, TextBox2 };//all your textboxes.

            RadioButtonList whoCallEvent = sender as RadioButtonList;


            string last = whoCallEvent.ID.ToString().Substring(whoCallEvent.ID.ToString().Length - 1, 1);//get the last symbol of object (TextBox) ID,  who call event. 
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(last);
            if (Convert.ToInt32(whoCallEvent.SelectedValue) == 5)
            {
                textboxes[index - 1].Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                textboxes[index - 1].Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

But I think this is conceptually wrong to do it this way. The best way is to create `rbl_SelectedIndexChanged` for all the `radioButtonList` you have on my page.

Comment: Using your method I'll have to create rbl1_SelectedIndexChanged for all the radioButtonList I have on my page. I want to create a single function that can take care of TextBox enabling/disabling